# Ionic 2: Why does alert box look like old Android?

Tags: angular, alert, ionic2, android-version

Why does the alert in my Ionic 2 app look like an old Android version and how can I change this?

Note: this is just calling JavaScript

```
alert()
```

function, NOT the Alert component! I am doing this on purpose.

[image]

For comparison, this is an alert from a website in the browser:

[image]

I'm concerned that the browser version/sdk it's building to is out of date.

Why are these looking different?

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar"
```

In platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml